How to build React Native Expo app using env variables from eas secret?
I have a .env file:
REACT_APP_URL={value}
REACT_APP_API_URL={value}
REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL={value}
REACT_APP_NAME={value}
REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_ID={value}
REACT_APP_WEBSITE_URL={value}

That is my current file of eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 10.0.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

I have stored these values in eas secret by running the command:
eas secret:push --scope project --env-file .env

I have stored on env some secret but the problem is when I run the app the env values are not stored in the build

when i run eas build --platform android --non-interactive --no-wait
I get this:
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile: no environment variables specified

How can i load the env from the eas secret I have added, so when i build i can run the application with those variables?

How did you use env? Show us your codes. Have you used expo/env? Or you did use it within the built-in expo ability?

@AmerllicA I have used the default .env that is in the root of the app, I have also updated the question. Please have a look at that.

When you go to the expo web portal > project settings > secrets do you find those env variables you set there?
And if you check the build logs > spin up environment step, are you able to find the variables under "Environment secrets"?

Expo environment variables
Actually, your .env file should contain the variables like the following:
EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://staging.example.com
EXPO_PUBLIC_API_KEY=abc123

And inside your codes, you can use the variables like the following:
import { Button } from 'react-native';

function Post() {
  const apiUrl = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL;

  async function onPress() {
    await fetch(apiUrl, { ... })
  }

  return <Button onPress={onPress} title="Post" />;
}

For more information about using Expo environment variables you can read this link.
HINT: Use the exact phrase process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_XXX to get the variable from the .env file. The _XXX is your custom name.

EAS Build
To have a correct EAS Build you should write the eas.json file like the following:
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://api.development.com"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://api.production.com"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://api.test.com"
      }
    }
  }
}

To have a better understanding of EAS Build configuration you can have a look at this link.

Thank you for your comment, but the problem with this is that I store the env variables in a eas.json for the build, and I wanted to keep the variables safe. That is the main reason why I chose to use eas secret.
Regarding the usage of EXPO_PUBLIC as prefix, I have used REACT_APP as prefix and have used, I have used like this const finalUrl = ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/unauth/test has worked.

@n9p4, You did all things fully custom. awesome, move on. About the eas.json, I thing it is the only way. I haven't any other solution. Apologize

No worries, thank you for your time and suggestions!


Store the secrets in eas secrets

Update your eas.json like this
 "production": {
 "env": {
     "EXPO_PUBLIC_YOUR_KEY_NAME": "EXPO_PUBLIC_YOUR_KEY_NAME"
 }

}

On eas build  --platform ios. Ensure it says
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile:

Test and ensure it works


I was struggled to get the env injection working too. This ensure safety for the env variable. Hope this helps

But how will link the secret name stored in eas secret with the value EXPO_PUBLIC_YOUR_KEY_NAME ?
